# How to hide an option in a dropdown menu PHP?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP, and would like to know if there is any way to hide an option depending on what I get,
basiccaly this is my code it's simple.

```
<?php 
require 'database.php';
session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $state=$_GET['state'];
    $sql="SELECT * from states";
    $show=$conn->prepare($sql); 
    $show->execute();
    $result = $show->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
}else{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $state=$_POST['state']; 
    $sql="UPDATE pqrs SET fk_state=:fk_state WHERE idPqrs=:id";
    $update=$conn->prepare($sql); 
    $update->bindParam(':id',$_POST['id']);
    $update->bindParam(':fk_state',$_POST['state']);
    $update->execute();
}
?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
     <div class="ml-5"><?php require 'partials/header.php' ?></div>
        <div class="container col-5">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Extreme Techonologics</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">Ingrese los campos a cambiar</h2>
            <form action="pqr_update.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id?>" class="form-control" name="id">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group my-5">
                    <label for="pqr_type">Seleccione el estado del PQR:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                    <?php foreach($result as $state):?>   
                    <option value="<?php echo $state['idState'];?>"><?php echo $state['state'];?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>             
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>
    </body>
    </html>
</html>
```

Basically I would like to know if when `$ _GET = ['state'] = 'Nuevo'`, when I press the `button (name = 'update')` what I receive from the `POST`, it only shows me an option (En Ejecución), in theory there are 3 states , Nuevo, En Ejecución and Cerrado. When the status is ¿Nuevo' I don't want it to show me the option "EN Ejecucuion" and when the option received is "EN Ejecucuion" I do not want it to show me the option 'Nuevo'.

Comment: You could modify the query that retrieves the states to include something like "where idState <> " whatever the current state value is.

Comment: @droopsnoot I don't get it, could you please be more specific?

Comment: Actually now I've read it again, it's not quite the question I thought it was. It may be easier to have the loop that draws the option list check the current state value when it draws each option.

Comment: @droopsnoot well how can i do, that.

Comment: The horrible way is to just use an `if` inside your loop for each condition that you have. If the current state is nuevo and the one you're about to display is "en ejecucion" then don't display it. And vice versa. If it was simply that you did not want to display the current state (which is how I read it in the first place) then it would be easier again. Either way it means hard-coding things to check certain id values, which I don't like, but I don't know enough about your situation to think of anything better.

Comment: @droopsnoot i get thanks dude, you clarify everything for me, you can solve the problem using the conditional as you said and evaluating the current $ _REQUEST (which I did not know was used, because I am learning php) in the same way thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above requirement, try this:

```
<?php 
require 'database.php';
session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $state=$_GET['state'];
    $sql="SELECT * from states";
    $show=$conn->prepare($sql); 
    $show->execute();
    $result = $show->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
}else{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $state=$_POST['state']; 
    $sql="UPDATE pqrs SET fk_state=:fk_state WHERE idPqrs=:id";
    $update=$conn->prepare($sql); 
    $update->bindParam(':id',$_POST['id']);
    $update->bindParam(':fk_state',$_POST['state']);
    $update->execute();
}
?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
     <div class="ml-5"><?php require 'partials/header.php' ?></div>
        <div class="container col-5">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Extreme Techonologics</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">Ingrese los campos a cambiar</h2>
            <form action="pqr_update.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id?>" class="form-control" name="id">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group my-5">
                    <label for="pqr_type">Seleccione el estado del PQR:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                    <?php
                        foreach($result as $state):
                            if (
                                  ($_REQUEST['state'] == '¿Nuevo\'' && $state['state'] != 'EN Ejecucuion')
                                  &&
                                  ($_REQUEST['state'] == 'EN Ejecucuion' && $state['state'] != '¿Nuevo\'')
                            ):
                    ?>   
                        <option value="<?php echo $state['idState'];?>"><?php echo $state['state'];?></option>
                    <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>
    </body>
    </html>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem correct to me. I can't see how you'd ever get a true out of checking that the request-state is both "nuevo" _and_ "en ejecucion", which would mean that none of the options display, surely?

Comment: the state is in `$_REQUEST['state']` and the `$state` is from the `$results` foreach loop. As per my understanding, the `$_REQUEST` contains both the get and post values. So based on the above requirement I have given the solution.

Comment: @droopsnoot You are right, the code is wrong, but the resolution of the problem is adequate for this case, I made some modifications to the code according to what I want and it served, if you like, I can share the code.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju my point is that your `if()` clause only displays the state inside the loop if `$_REQUEST['state']=="Nuevo"` __and__ `$_REQUEST['state']=="En ejecucion"`. That cannot be correct, how can that one variable have two separate values at the same time?

Comment: The `$_REQUEST['state']` has only one value at a time. The if condition is validating one of the 2 scenarios.